# How to use UIImagePickerController to select photos directly

Tags: ios, swift

I am using UIImagePickerController to select photos. But it will show the list of album first, I have to select a album then go into that album to select photo. How can I specify a default album and let image picker controller to select the photos in that album directly?

Comment: Why do you need this? You should let the user choose which album of photos they want to pick from.

Comment: Since the camera roll is usually the default one, we want to show the photos in this camera roll first. At the same time, we also need to let user select different album

Answer (score 1):

I guess all you can do is to choose among these three options `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`, `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`.

If all you wanted to do is to open Camera Roll album directly, specify `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`. I don't think you can get more specific than that.